# Como hacer una validación en 2 tablas distintas de bases de datos? MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito realizar una búsqueda en una tabla de una base de datos, donde el un campo sea = 1 y que además en otra tabla (obvio relacionada) de otra base de datos, si la descripción proporcionada existe en alguna de las tablas deberá enviarse mensaje de que el siguiente campo ya ha sido capturado.

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName  
FROM BD1 c (nolock)   
WHERE c.Inactive=0   
AND c.IsForTesting=0  
AND c.CustomerTypeID = 1 
order by CustomerName
```

Necesito relacionar el resultado con la siguiente tabla, BD2 (con el campo CustomerName)
Me falta la segunda parte.
Necesito que esa información que arroje, relacionarla con la BD2, si existe, tengo que arrojar un mensaje.

Tienen alguna idea de cómo hacer la consulta?

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Qué has probado? Puedes enseñarnos tu código?

Comment: Como son las tablas? un ejemplo? debes ser mas claro al preguntar. mira [ask]

Comment: Ya edité, disculpen por mi error, realmente casi no hago preguntas..

Comment: agrega un ejemplo de datos y cuando si y cuando no debe pasar esto

Comment: y en tu query de ejemplo, cual seria la tabla relacionada? como se relacionan?

Comment: te sugiero investigues "SQL JOIN", hay mucha literatura en internet al respecto. Es sencillo de aprender.